# Session array giving same results on different machines and not destroying itself after specified time

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

I have a session array which functions to store the IDs of posts from the `accessories` post type. The purpose of this is to achieve a "recently viewed posts" block.

So, when someone clicks into a post that belongs to the `accessories` post type, it will store that ID into the session array. Then, in the arguments for the query, I'm just passing the array variable.

**Issues:**

1. I'm accessing my local site on another machine and the array is returning the same results as they were on my other machine. I don't want users to see the same stuff
2. After 24 hours, I want the session to destroy itself (reset itself). However, it's been a few days and the session is still active.

At the very top of `header.php` I have defined my session:

```html
<?php
session_start();

// Check if the session variable exists

if(!isset($_SESSION['recently_viewed'])){
  // if it doesn't, create an empty array
  $_SESSION['recently_viewed'] = array();
}

// if accessories post type, then get ID and add to array

if ( is_singular ( 'accessories' ) ):
  global $post;
  $current_post_id = $post->ID;

  if ( !in_array ($current_post_id, $_SESSION['recently_viewed']) ):
    $_SESSION['recently_viewed'][] = $current_post_id;
  endif;

endif;

// destroy session after 24 hours

if( !isset($_SESSION['creationTime']) ){
  $_SESSION['creationTime'] = time();
}

if (time() - $_SESSION['creationTime'] <= 60*60*24 ){
  // still today
} else {
  session_destroy();
}

?>
```

Then, the arguments I'm running are:

```html
<?php

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'accessories',
  'post__in' => $_SESSION['recently_viewed'],
  'posts_per_page' => '5',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);

?>
```

Any ideas why I'm facing those issues?

Comment: The same session being available on multiple clients seem to indicate that the `session_id` is being set to a static value somewhere in your code. Verify that you have the same session identifier on both clients (look at the cookie value). Regarding the session being destroyed, start by making sure that `session_destroy` is actually being called. You might also have some test data around that's populating your session with the same information. Since this isn't a complete, self-contained verifiable example it's hard to say exactly what's happening.

Comment: That isn't really the way to start/destroy PHP sessions in WordPress, but anyway, have you considered using the [transients API](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) instead? Or try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/)?

Comment: Why are you trying to destroy entire session which could have other data as well.
You should instead reset session array to empty upon 24 hours are passed. 

Also as @MatsLindh said, ensure that same session ID is not being used across different machines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  // Initialiser la session
  session_start();
  
  // Détruire la session.
  if(session_destroy())
  {
    // Redirection vers la page de connexion
    header("Location: login.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

check `$_SESSION['recently_viewed']` value that you correctly add accessories item to array. Maybe your mistake is some other where. Shortly your codes seems correct to me.

Also be sure that are you really eliminate `$_SESSION['recently_viewed']` array values from your query conditions...

Answer (score -1):

When you run this code all the users of the session are disconnected and redirected to the page chosen here login.php